# Let $Z_m \to c$ in probability. When can we say $EZ_m \to c, Var[Z_m] \to 0?$ Could you please see if my proof is correct in a special case?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, solution-verification

Let $Z_m \to c$ in probability. Then when can we say $EZ_m \to c$ and $Var[Z_m] \to 0?$

I think a sufficient condition is that: *$|Z_m|$ is uniformly bounded*, i.e. $|Z_m| \le K \forall m.$

QUESTION 1: **Here's my proof of the above claim: could you please check if it's correct?**

Fix $\epsilon > 0.$ Then:  $Z_m \to c$ in probability implies $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\forall m \ge N, P[|Z_m - c| \ge \epsilon]  \le \epsilon .....(1)$

$|EZ_m - c| \le E|Z_m - c| = \int_{|Z_m - c| \ge \epsilon}  |Z_m - c|dP + \int_{|Z_m - c| < \epsilon}  |Z_m - c| dP  \le \int_{|Z_m - c| \ge \epsilon}  (|Z_m| + c)dP +  \int_{|Z_m - c| < \epsilon}  |Z_m - c| dP \le (K+ |c) \epsilon  + \epsilon,$ where we used (1) above to get the left summand on the right side of the last inequality. This shows that $|EZ_m - c| \le (K + |c| + 1) \epsilon,$ proving what we wanted: is the proof correct?

The proof of $Var[Z_m] \to 0$ is very similar as above.

QUESTION 2: When can we weaken the condition i.e. $|Z_m| \le K \forall m$ and still have $EZ_m \to c$ and $Var[Z_m] \to 0$ when $Z_m \to c$ in probability?

Answer (score 1):

Your claim is true. In fact, it is a special case of the result found under "Relation to convergence of random variables" here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability. Note that $(|Z_m|)_m$ being uniformly bounded implies that also $(|Z_m|^2)_m$ is uniformly bounded (by $K^2$), which implies that both are uniformly integrable and hence $L^1$ convergent, which gives the result you want. This also gives a weaker condition: it is sufficient that $(Z_m)_m$ are uniformly integrable to obtain that $EZ_m\to c$. For the variance, it is sufficient that $(Z_m^2)_m$ are uniformly integrable.

Your proof looks fine, only minor detail is that you write $\forall n\geq N$, but that should be $m$ rather than $n$.